# reversed supply to 3 phase ups system

Tags: backup

we have just put a new 3 phase supply to our computer room and the three phase ups system has had problems.
the engineer from schneider says that the supply phases are in the wrong direction.
I understand that a motor can rotate cw or ccw by reversing the phases but why would this cause a problem on a ups system ?.

any info would be very welcome.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer a question about a problem whose entire description of the problem consists of saying that the system "has had problems".

Answer (score 2):

To flip the question around: What kind of crazy, low-quality, 3-phase UPS would allow power that is incorrectly phased to be passed to the load? What if the load is a motor?

The whole point of a UPS system is to monitor the quality of the incoming power and prevent incorrect or out of specification voltages from being passed to the load. If you feed it incorrect voltages in the first place, expecting it to pass that power to the load as if it was perfectly fine is unreasonable.

Comment: True - but presumably the UPS is correcting the supply since user196913 is asking us. But maintaining this for a long period of time will put a lot of stress on the UPS and shorten it's lifespan.